# Spring Mail inline Images not getting attached

Tags: java, spring

I Have written a code for sending mails with inline images.

```
final MimeMessagePreparator messagePreparator = new MimeMessagePreparator() {
                @Override
                public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {
                    MimeMessageHelper mimeMessageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, MimeMessageHelper.MULTIPART_MODE_RELATED);
                    mimeMessageHelper.setTo(mailTo);

                    mimeMessageHelper.setSubject(subject);
                    mimeMessageHelper.setText(mailContent,true);
                    InternetAddress fromAddress = new InternetAddress(mailFromEmail,mailFromName);
                    mimeMessageHelper.setFrom(fromAddress);
                    for(String inlineImage : inlineImages) {
                        attachImage(mimeMessageHelper, inlineImage);
                    }

                }
            };
```

An this code was working perfectly. 
But later on it was required to send the mail in some regional language and so the code fails.
So I change my code to

```
final MimeMessagePreparator messagePreparator = new MimeMessagePreparator() {
                @Override
                public void prepare(MimeMessage mimeMessage) throws Exception {
                    MimeMessageHelper mimeMessageHelper = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, MimeMessageHelper.MULTIPART_MODE_RELATED);
                    mimeMessageHelper.setTo(mailTo);

                    /**
                     * for allowing UTF-8 encoding in mail body ie support for regional languages
                     */

                    MimeBodyPart att = new MimeBodyPart();
                    att.setText(mailContent, "UTF-8", "plain");
                    att.addHeader("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=UTF-8");

                    Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
                    multipart.addBodyPart(att);
                    mimeMessage.setContent(multipart);

                    /**
                     * for allowing UTF-8 encoding in mail body ie support for regional languages ends
                     */

                    mimeMessageHelper.setSubject(subject);
//                    mimeMessageHelper.setText(mailContent,true);
                    InternetAddress fromAddress = new InternetAddress(mailFromEmail,mailFromName);
                    mimeMessageHelper.setFrom(fromAddress);
                    for(String inlineImage : inlineImages) {
                        attachImage(mimeMessageHelper, inlineImage);
                    }
                }
            };
```

attachImage method is :

```
private void attachImage(MimeMessageHelper mimeMessageHelper,String imageName) throws MessagingException{
        mimeMessageHelper.addInline(imageName, new ClassPathResource("mailimg/" + imageName));
    }
```

Now language is showing fine but the inline images are not getting attached. I am not getting if the language support is not how it meant to be or anything else.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried without setting the content? and Using `new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, MimeMessageHelper.MULTIPART_MODE_RELATED, "UTF-8");` that should also allow for UTF-8 to be enabled without changing what you did...

Comment: Or without even changing the code you could configure the `JavaMailSenderImpl` with a `defaultEncoding` property set to `UTF-8`. That way your code remains unchanged and the only thing different would be a little line in your config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Revert the changes you made to your code, the only thing you seem to want to do is to have `UTF-8` encoding. There are easier and less intrusive ways to do that.

1. Configure the `JavaMailSenderImpl`.
2. Pass the encoding to the `MimeMessageHelper`

The first is the least intrusive. Just add a line to your configuration (if you are using XML) and all your mails will be send using UTF-8. Set the [`defaultEncoding`](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/JavaMailSenderImpl.html#setDefaultEncoding-java.lang.String-) property of the `JavaMailSenderImpl` to the encoding you want to use.

```
<bean id="mailSender" class=org.springframework.mail.javamail.JavaMailSenderImpl">
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>
```

The second is a bit more intrusive because you have to change code. The `MimeMessageHelper` has [a constructor that takes an encoding](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/mail/javamail/MimeMessageHelper.html#MimeMessageHelper-javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage-boolean-java.lang.String-). The only line in your (reverted) code you need to change is the constructing of the `MimeMessageHelper`.

```
MimeMessageHelper mimeMessageHelper = 
    new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, MimeMessageHelper.MULTIPART_MODE_RELATED, "UTF-8");
```

Either way should give you UTF-8 encoded emails and is a lot simpler.

Comment: thanks for suggestion ..checking and will let you know in a while

Comment: Its working fine ...i decided to enable UTF-8 encoding while configuring JavaMailSenderImpl...Thanks